# How to create parent object for subview with multiple UIImageViews in ViewController using iOS5

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, uiimageview, subview, iboutlet

In an iPhone app for iOS5 I'm trying to create a controller object that contains an image sub-view with multiple UIImageViews.  I have a main view controller with its associated main view and within this main view I have an multi-image sub-view and this sub-view has a dozen or more UIImageViews as configured in Interface Builder.  I have created a descendent of UIView and connected it as an IBOutlet connection for the ImageSubView in my ViewController.  I want to create IBOutlets for the dozen UIImageViews within my subView class, but Interface Builder will only let me create IBOutlets in my main ViewController not in the ImageSubView class. That is when I control drag from one of the UIImageViews it only shows creation of an IBOutlet if I drag within the MainViewController @interface code but not to the ImageSubView @interface code.  I want the details of controlling these dozen images to be hidden from the main ViewController.  I want the main ViewController to communicate to the ImageSubView only and for the ImageSubView to know how to manipulate the dozen images within it.  Do I need to create a sub-viewController?  If so how do I create a sub-viewController within the current main view? Interface Builder wouldn't let me drag another ViewController into the current main view.   Can there be multiple viewControllers (a main one and sub-controllers) for a single screen?

The view hierarchy looks like this:

```
MainViewController
    MainView
       ImageViewFullBackground
       ImageSubView
          UIImageView1
          UIImageView2
          . . . 
          UIImageView12
       Button1
       Button2
       . . .
       Button10
```

In response to Allen here is my ImageSubView header.  The class is actually called UILedNumericView

```
//
//  UINumericLabel.h
//  UILedNumericView
//
//  Created by Jon D. Newbill on 2/18/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Bitworks Systems Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UILedNumericView : UIView

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString * text;

// This is the numeric value of the LED display as a double
@property (nonatomic) double value;

// Returns true if the numeric display contains a decimal point
@property (readonly,nonatomic) BOOL hasDecimalPoint;

// Returns true if numeric display contains an exponent
@property (readonly,nonatomic) BOOL hasExponent;

// Returns true if numeric display is equal to zero.
@property (readonly,nonatomic) BOOL isZero;

// Returns number of characters in entire display
@property (readonly,nonatomic) NSUInteger length;

// Returns zero based character index of the E in the display
@property (readonly,nonatomic) NSUInteger exponentIndex;

// Returns or sets mantissa portion of display.  This is everything
// preceding the "E" on the display or the entire display if it does
// not contain an "E";
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString * mantissa;

// Returns or sets exponent portion of display.  This is everything
// following the "E" on the display.  If no E exists then an empty
// string is returned.  When set to a non-zero length string an E will
// be added to the display.
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString * exponent;

// Returns maximum allowed characters in display
// This includes digits, sign, decimal point and exponent
+ (NSUInteger) maxLength;

@end
```

Comment: can you post your ImageSubView.h file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the subviews from any view you have already gotten an IBOutlet from the interfacebuilder like this:

```
NSArray *subViewsArray = self.view.subviews; //Change this to the name of your view
UIView *view1 = [subViewsArray objectAtIndex:0]; //This selects view at position 0
NSLog(@"View1: %@",view1); //You can see what view you extracted (the properties)
```

There is no need for you to create a viewcontroller or something. However it is possible if you want but I don't believe it is what you want.

**Edit**: IBOutlets, as their name imply are used to tell the compiler to make a pointer to an item in the interface builder, so if you follow what I posted you are still creating those pointers programatically. If you want to have the "global" convenience of these as the IBOutlets have, just create a property for an UIView instead of declaring them locally like I did.

**Edit2**: Forgot to mention that the order of the views is the same as the order in the interface builder from top to down. (unless you changed them programatically)

Comment: Do you mean create IBOutlets in Main contrlr for the dozen UIImageViews and then access them from the sub-view to create an array of UIImageView's in the sub-view?  If so I knew I could do that.  But it would be a rather poor object oriented design.  The intent is to only connect the dozen sub-UIImageView's to the sub-view such that the View Controller has no visibility of the sub-UIImageView's.  

Or do you mean I don't need any IBOutlets but can access the images via their relationship between the sub-view and the dozen sub-images as represented in the view hierarchy in interface builder?

Comment: You dont need IBOutlets, you just need 1 for the main one. then if you see those subviews nested on the IB builder then you can access them trought the parent view like i explained in the code

Comment: Thanks!  In the Paul Hegarty's Stanford iPhone App class (ITunesU) there was such a point made of IBOutlets that I didn't realized that they are only needed to connect **controllers** to **views**.  It wasn't clear that relationships between sub-views were automatically connected.  That was the point I was missing.  I was trying to connect my subview to the dozen sub-imageViews but they were already connected and available via the **subviews** property. As the first with the answer to my question I'm awarding the 50 bounty points to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   int i,x,y;
   x=y=2;
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [mainScroll subviews];
      for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) [v removeFromSuperview];

      useD=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      imageArray=[useD objectForKey:LIVE];
      for( i=1;i<=[imageArray count] ;i++)
      {   
          iName=[imageArray objectAtIndex:i-1];
          UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:iName];
          UIImageView *mainImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
          [mainImageView setTag:i];
          [mainImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

          //for delete time tap and general tap gesture
          if(tapFlag)
          {
              tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self       action:@selector(imageDisplay:)];
              [mainImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
          }
          else
          {
              UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selection:)];
              [mainImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap2];
          }

          //for Border and lastAccessed Diff. Border
          if(lastAccessed==i)
          {
              [mainImageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
              [mainImageView.layer setBorderWidth:2];
          }
          else
          {
              [mainImageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
              [mainImageView.layer setBorderWidth:2]; 
          }
          //for rounded UIImageView
          CALayer * l = [mainImageView layer];
          [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
          [l setCornerRadius:10.0];


          CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x,y,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
          mainImageView.frame = frame;


          x+=WIDTH;
          if(i%orientation==0)
          {
              x=2;
              y=y+HEIGHT+5;
          }
          else
          {
              x=x+GAP;
          }
          [mainScroll addSubview:mainImageView];

      }
      [mainScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0,(i-1)*add)];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First: declare IBOutlets in ImageSubView header (UILedNumericView.h I suppose). One for each UIImageView
Second: go to Interface Builder and be sure to set the class for ImageSubView to UILedNumericView as that is the class of ImageSubView.
Third: Control drag from each imageView# to ImageSubView in the left of Interface Builder (the schematic view with a tree of views).
Fourth: the list of IBOutlets appears and you select the right one.
Fifth: synth all IBOutlets and code some methods to manage them in UILedNumericView.m

If I have understood your problem, that is the obvious solution.

Pass third can be done selecting ImageSubView and from the right pannel, where you have the complete list of selected object outlets and you can drag from them to imageViews.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply design your ImageSubView as a separate UIView. Layout that subview inside it's own .xib file. Then ensure your subclass implements `initWithCoder:`. You may then add the subview to your ImageViewController. Just ensure that all objects within the .xib have their custom classes defined.

Let me know if some images, or a sample project would help you to understand this concept a bit more. Sometimes the work that IB does behind the scenes can seem like magic, but once you understand it, you will see the great power behind it.

Comment: I started development in IOS5,I'm not familiar with XIB files.  I thought that Storyboards replaced XIB.  Are there things that can't be done with Storyboards that still require XIB?  And yes further explanation would be helpful.  My read of initWithCoder is it implements a form of serialization used to archive objects.  Not sure how that applies here.  I just want to create a sub-object that is responsible (encapsulates) a set of imageView's so to the ViewController it just looks like it's a single object.  In particular it will look like a numeric display made up of a collection of images.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to hide logics into an object different from `MainViewController` I suggest you to create a second controller, eg. `ImageSubViewController`. You can define it's appearance through a dedicate NIB file, in which you link all your `UIImageViews` to the parent `ImageSubViewController` and its `IBOutlets`.

Then, I suggest you to do this:

1. Add a generic `UIView` component to the `MainViewController`'s view, and an `IBOutlet` to handle it (let's call it `imageSubView`)
2. Add a property to `MainViewController` to handle an instance of `ImageSubViewController` (let's call it `imageSubViewController`)
3. Inside `MainViewController`, in the `viewDidLoad` method, instantiate the `ImageSubViewController` and then add its view to the previously created placeholder:

   `[self.imageSubView addSubView:imageSubViewController.view];`

This way you will have your custom subview inside the `MainViewController`, and you can control its behavior through the `ImageSubViewController` instance, even each sub image view outlet, eg. via `imageSubViewController.image1`, `imageSubViewController.image2`, etc.

I think that this way you will have a good implementation for your solution, with a great decoupling between the main controller and the custom subview's behavior. Let me know if this helps.